# Python - Why do nonlocal and global variables need to be declared?

Tags: python-3.x, scope, namespaces, global-variables

Why is the following piece of code in a plain Python 3.x module considered invalid syntax? I'm interested in the design considerations that guided the decision of requiring explicit declaring of global and nonlocal variables before assignment.

```
def foo():
    global a = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value:

> This explicit declaration is required in order to remind you that (unlike the superficially analogous situation with class and instance variables) you are actually modifying the value of the variable in the outer scope

This suggests the previous declaration of `global a` before altering its value is a safety measure for the programmer. Another reason may be that Python is is a dynamically-typed language, so if you think about it, that particular line looks nothing like regular Python code.

I encourage you to read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement and experiment with the language. Finally, you could ask a core developer of the language in one of its mailing lists here: 
https://www.python.org/community/lists/. If you find anything interesting, please share it with the community.

Answer (score 0):

`global` keyword indicates that the variable should be looked up in the global namespace as in `globals()`. It's nothing like `const` declaration in `c++`. So before you refer to the `global a = 1`, the variable `a` should've been created.

```py
def foo():
    global a
```

This works fine without `SyntaxError`. But since `a` is not defined before function `foo`, the interpreter will return a `NameError` when you call `foo()`.

In conclusion, keyword `global` is used to modify a variable defined in global scope inside a local scope like a function.